# Trouble with SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly and AllDirectories

Tags: c#

I have a program that is used to identify and copy select files. It works fine for set paths I know will be in a specific location and I have recently gotten it to work if I at least know the top level directory a file will be stored in with a wildcard name using this:

```
string Fol = "C:\testpath\test";  
string[] testfol = Directory.GetFiles(Fol, "filename-*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);  
if (Directory.Exists(Fol))  
    foreach (var file in testfol)  
    {  
        defaultPaths.Add($@"{file}");  
    }
```

The defaultPaths.Add piece adds the file to be collected to my list of standard items I always collect.

The problem is that if I try to use "SearchOption.AllDirectories" is doesn't actually search the subdirectories (or even the root directory of Fol and skips this attempted file copy altogether). Any reason the logic behind SearchOption.AllDirectories is operating differently than .TopDirectoryOnly?

Comment: So to be clear, are you looking for files that literally start with "filename-"? As that's what the code is doing

Comment: In this sample, yes. There are a few different wildcard paths I'll eventually want to look for, but just in terms of how this should work in this situation, I am looking for "filename-*".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `EnumerationOptions` instead of `SearchOptions.AllDirectories`. Latter does not work at all how it should.

```
string[] filezFol = Directory.GetFiles(
    @"D:\",
    "*.xml",

    new EnumerationOptions
    {
        RecurseSubdirectories = true

    });
foreach (var file in filezFol)
{
    defaultPaths.Add($@"{file}");
}
```

Found in the .NET GitHub page on a mostly unrelated request: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32883